# Error while trying to install MSGPACK

Tags: server, console, php

I'm trying to install [MSGPACK](http://msgpack.org/) to be used with PHP, by following the [wiki guide](http://wiki.msgpack.org/display/MSGPACK/QuickStart+for+PHP).

But when I run `sudo ./configure` I get this error:

```
checking PHP version... configure: error: need at least PHP 5 or newer
```

When I run: `php -v`:

```
PHP 5.3.5-1ubuntu7.2 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: May 2 2011 23:18:30)
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

While you might have the PHP interpreter installed, the configure script is probably searching for the files necessary to compile new PHP extension modules.  Those files are found in the [php5-dev[image: Install php5-dev]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/php5-dev) package.  Try installing that?

```
sudo apt-get install php5-dev
```

Comment: Hi. Already have php5-dev installed.

Comment: Okay, then please provide some more information in your question.  The configure script should have generated a `config.log` file that might contain some more details of the failure.